# When a call made to Word.run function, I am getting 'Word' is undefined in word 2016

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

**Issue:**

- Here I am using an word add-in in word 2016. When a call a function
  which uses Word.run is giving an error as 'Word' is undefined.
- The add-in file is working properly in office 365 desktop application as well as in browser.

**NOTE: I am initialising word before calling the Word.run**

**What I have Checked?**

- Cleared the cache and checked out.
- Version of Office-js is latest.
- Using latest schema in xml i.e 1.1.
- All the resources are defined properly in xml file.

The function call is made from a html page to a js page where the Word.run will execute. the office is initialised in the html page when the page get's loaded.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets, Word 2016 supports the WordApi 1.1 requirement set, so it should recognize the Word object. I wonder if the error is misleading and the real problem is that you are calling an API from version 1.2 (or later) of the requirement set.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried with WordApi 1.1 then also I am getting the same error Word is undefined

Comment: In that case, if you don't get an answer in the next couple of days, I suggest you create an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).